# sizeof 3 dimensional array of char in valgrind

Tags: c++, arrays

I use char ***block to create a 3 dimensional array, allocate it with new and initialize it to '0':

```
block = new char**[x_size]; 
for(int i = 0; i < x_size; ++i)
{
    block[i] = new char*[y_size];
    for(int j = 0; j < y_size; ++j)
    {
        block[i][j] = new char[z_size];
        for(int k = 0; k < z_size ;++k)
            block[i][j][k] = '0';
    }
}
```

This array should contain 1600 char (5*5*64). Considering a char is 1 byte, shouldn't the array be 1600 bytes?
In valgrind I get 75568 bytes allocated and 33 allocs. This is done in a minimal class that has a constructor, a destructor and in private:

```
char ***block;
const int x_size = 5, y_size = 5, z_size = 64;
```

Im using char because I need the best performance, but I tried with int and I get the same exact memory allocated in valgrind. Is there a way to know the exact space a variable takes in memory?

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? If you program in C++ then I strongly recommend you use `std::vector` instead. Especially since being called a [three start programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is usually *not* a compliment.

Comment: More related to your question, *how* do you know that Valgrind think its 75568 bytes in 33 allocations? How do you check it? Do you have any other dynamic allocations?

Comment: "I'm using char because I need the best performance" - then don't use a structure that requires three dereferences and is horridly cache-inefficient. Use a linear single-dim `char` sequence of `x_size*y_size*z_size`(`std::vector` would work marvelously) and do the index math.

Comment: Also, don't fall into the trap of *premature optimization*. First of all make sure your code is nice, well formatted, readable and maintainable, and of course *works*. *Then* you profile and measure to see *if* the performance is adequate. If not then you find the bottlenecks and optimize those.

Comment: Using C++ but I read that char* might have better performance and memory wise than std::vector. Didn't know about the three star programmer, I had a good laugh. But I come from C and pointer don't have the slightest effect on me! So what would be the difference performance wise between make a new class and using ***?

Comment: With 8 bytes pointer size your program need to allocate 5 pointers to a pointer (total 5*8 = 40) next for every new pointer program need to allocate 5 pointers to a pointer (total 40 + 5*5*8=40 + 200 = 240) and finally for each pointer you allocate 64 int array and in total it is 40 + 200 + 1600 = 1840 that is minimum size without memory alignment in bytes for your 3d array (but it's not real 3d it's complex multipointer array). And it's total of 31 allocations (1+5+25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you are not allocate only 1600 octet but you are allocate pointer too:

In 64 bit:

1. 5 * 8 = 40
2. 5 * 5 * 8 = 200
3. 5 * 5 * 64 * 1 = 1600

With C and valgrind, I have exactly 1840 octet and 31 block.

The rest is probably some C++ routine.

Comment: A little reference to my comment would be appreciated ;)

Comment: @Logman you have commented at 2016-12-11 10:43:26Z, my last edit is at 2016-12-11 10:30:47Z. A little reference to my answer will be appreciated ;). If I had taken your comment, I would of course put you as a reference.

Comment: That's true and in the same time weird as when I added my comment there was no answers at all, but timestamps don't lie ;) sorry for false accusations.